How to generate/find dataset of global cities in multiple languages?
I'm trying to create a global city dataset in multiple languages. I found a few approaches, but none seem reliable enough. Looking for free/cheap solutions. Below is an ideal example of CSV data I'd like to achieve:
country_en,state_en,county_en,name_en,country_es,state_es,county_es,name_es,lat,lng
France,,,Paris,Francia,,,París,48.8566,2.3522
United Kingdom,,,Birmingham,Reino Unido,,,Birmingham,52.4862,-1.8904
United States,Alabama,Jefferson County,Birmingham,Estados Unidos,Alabama,Condado de Jefferson,Birmingham,33.5186,-86.8104
United States,California,Los Angeles,Los Angeles,Estados Unidos,California,Los Ángeles,Los Ángeles,34.0522,-118.2437
United Arab Emirates,,,Dubai,Emiratos Árabes Unidos,,,Dubái,25.276987,55.296249

The main idea here is that Birmingham is a unique city in the UK, there is no need to store a county against it. But there are few cities called Birmingham in the US, so we're storing county and state against them to make them unique.
I'm trying to find/generate a dataset of all cities with over 15k population in multiple languages.
So far I haven't found any way to generate that sort of pattern. The closest thing I could find is this repo: joelacus/world-cities. It's exactly what I'm looking for, except this one is in English only.
I also tried using Wikidata, but the results tend to be unreliable (hopefully because of my limited ability to write good queries). This is a query I tried. The issue with this is that some labels are not consistent. For example, a county label sometimes returns a city, and sometimes a country. In case of Birmingham, UK, it returns to Birmingham instead of West Midlands. In the case of Moscow, Russia, the county field contains Russia.
Another approach I was thinking of is getting the data via Google Maps API. Because I have a dataset with GPS coordinates, I could supply it into the query and return the formatted city.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=48.8566,2.3522&result_type=locality&language=es&key=your-api-key

This returns a well formatted string most of time:
...
            "formatted_address": "París, Francia",
...

I believe I could generate a new CSV localized dataset using this endpoint. However this means I'd need to hit that endpoint over 100k times for one language only and that might not end well.
Any ideas?

You might also consider OpenStreetMap.
You can use:

Nominatim with its API, but I do not see a "population field in this query". See its usage policy.
the openstreetmap API v0.6 in a local OpenStreetMap dataset.
The Overpass API using tags

When I look for Dubai (which does include a population field), I see with Nominatim 140 names, which could be used for dataset in multiple languages:
دبي (name)
Doebai (name:af)
ዱባይ (name:am)
Dubai (name:an)
دبي (name:ar)
ডুবাই (name:as)
Дубай (name:ba)
Дубай (name:be)
Дубай (name:bg)
...

The Nominatim API supports multiple languages. It can be installed locally, including using a docker image.
I didn't find a way to query by population directly, but, using a local OSM dataset copy, you might be able to query "place=city" and filter out the ones matching your criteria.

Thanks for the response. I'll check it out but I'm currently investigating https://download.geonames.org/export/dump/ they seem to have all the data I need (city, admin area, GPS coordinates, alternate city name, alternate admin area name) it's just matter of joining a few tables together which I'm currently in trying to do with Pandas. The tables required for this are: admin1CodesASCII.txt, alternateNamesV2.zip and cities15000.zip. I'm trying to define a 3 way relationship between these tables

The open source database at https://github.com/dr5hn/countries-states-cities-database contains many cities (over 150,000) including multiple translations.
It contains JSON formatted data with all the information requested.
The default CSV exports in the repo don't include translations by default but scripts/export_csv.php can be modified to reinclude it. Just remove the below from the file.
    // No translations please.
    unset($headings['translations']);

Then to export run php -f scripts/export_csv.php (note, php must be installed)

Alternatively check the bin folder and look through the files there to get inspiration on implementing a similar data aggregator to generate your own database
